# Raster division using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, error-000732

How do you do raster division (ArcPy raster calculation)? I want to divide the “.tif” in one folder by the “.tif” in the other folder.

This is my code：

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1"

raster_list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*")

print (raster_list1)

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test2"

raster_list2 = arcpy.ListRasters("*")

print (raster_list2)

try:

    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":

        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

        print ("Checked out \"Spatial\" Extension")

    else:

        raise LicenseError

except LicenseError:

    print "Spatial Analyst license is unavailable"

except:

    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

for raster1 in raster_list:

    ras1 = raster1

for raster2 in raster_list2:

    ras2 = raster2

    outraster = Raster(ras1)/ Raster(ras2) 
      
    outraster.save(r"C:\Users\yutao\Desktop\test1" + "\\1" + ras1)*
```

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-36e5c3a3bfbf> in <module>()

      for raster2 in raster_list2:

          ras2 = raster2

--->      outraster = Raster(ras1)/Raster(ras2)

          outraster.save(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1" + "\\1" + ras1)
     

RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset 2001maxndvi.tif does not exist or is not supported
```

Comment: Use Raster Calculator https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help，however my processed is a loop rasters（.tif).I dont know how to process it.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1"
raster_list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test2"
```

No rasters in `raster_list1` will be found since you've changed the workspace afterwards and arcpy will try to find them in `test2` folder.

Try:

```
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1"
raster_list1 = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
raster_list1 = [os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, r) for r in raster_list1]
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test2"
```

Then the rasters in `raster_list1` will have full path and filename, not only the filenames and you can change workspace and arcpy will still find them.

Comment: YES ！thank you very much! but now I have a new problem. 
   outraster.save(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1\" + "1" + raster1)   this outpath   is  error.

Comment: thank you! How do I put the results in a folder

Comment: Nice! Im not sure what you are trying to do with `outraster.save(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1" + "\\1" + ras1)` but use os path join here aswell. What is `\\1`, a subfolder called `1` or the prefix to the filename `ras1`?

Comment: As long as you can output the results to be validated.test1 is a folder.I don't know how to save the results to test1 and still distinguish the results.

Comment: If you dont save the results to a new folder then when you rerun the code `raster_list1` will be a mix of old and new data. `outraster.save(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1\1", ras1))`, you need to create the folder `1` manually. But if you want the same folder you can add a filename prefix using format, `os.path.join(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1", 'divided_{0}'.format(ras1))`

Comment: Thank you very much!If I have 20 output results and I want to put them in the test1 folder, what would be the name of the 20 results?

Comment: outraster.save(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\giser\Desktop\test1",'divided_{0}'.format(ras1))
may be is error: invalid syntax.